# Real-Time signal envelop

Tags: signals, real-time, envelope

I have a real-time signal as input in my c++ code and I acummulate it in a vector. The length is fixed to 200 values and I want to compute the envelope of the signal.

Do you have any idea about a library or an existing code to compute a real time envelope?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: What kind of signal do you have, and what do you mean by envelope?

Comment: The signal if have EMG. The envelope of an oscillating signal is a smooth curve outlining its extremes.